# Flip Image after taking picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing the front facing camera app in `UIImagePickercontroller`.

When I capture the image it's shows as flipped from left to right.

How can I flip it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:picture.CGImage scale:picture.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];

picture = flippedImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(image.transform, -1, 1);
```